# Do variables declared in constructors persist in the created object

Tags: java, variables, constructor, scope

If I want to declare a temp int within the constructor of an object, will that variable stay in memory after the construction is finished. Or will garbage collection remove it after its finished?

Comment: When there are no pointers to a variable, it is removed

Comment: What is a temp int? It is not a keyword in java.

Comment: @AnindaBhattacharyya OP means a variable to hold a value temporarily

Comment: If there's no variable pointing to it outside the scope of the constructor, it'll be removed.

Comment: Why would you consider a constructor any different from any other block of code in this regard? There's no magic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the variable goes out of scope and you're not keeping a reference to it and garbage collection runs, it will be removed from memory.
This is not guaranteed to happen right after the constructor finishes executing, though - it can take some time, depending on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

`int`, `long`, `boolean` and other primitive variables are never garbage collected as they occupy space in the thread stack.

Their memory utilisation is recovered the moment that the method call (including constructors) returns to the caller.